# discord.js V13 Invite Tracker TypeError: client.guilds.cache.get(...).fetchInvites is not a function

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to code a invite tracker this is the code :

```
let invites;



client.on('ready', async() => {
    await wait(2000);

    client.guilds.cache.get("926674245357039657").fetchInvites().then(inv => {
        invites = inv;
    })
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async(member) => {
    if(member.guild.id !== "926674245357039657") return;

    member.guild.fetchInvites().then(gInvites => {
        const invite = gInvites.find((inv) => invites.get(inv.code).uses < inv.uses);

        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('940362032253923348');

        channel.send(`${member} was invited by ${invite.inviter} and the code was ${invite.code}`);
    });
});
```

when i run the bot i get this error

```
client.guilds.cache.get("926674245357039657").fetchInvites().then(inv => {
                                                  ^

TypeError: client.guilds.cache.get(...).fetchInvites is not a function
```

can anyone help and thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchInvites` does not work in Discord v13, use `invites.fetch()` instead.

https://discordjs.guide/whats-new.html#guild